# Why is my Python script for loading API data to Azure hanging in PyCharm

Tags: python, database, pycharm, freeze

UPDATE: I have made the discovery that this only applies to one table (the appointments table). After playing around with the endpoint for this table, I have found that the script only hangs if the date specified in the parameter is before a certain date. I'll give an example below:

```
appointments_read_endpoint = f'https://api{environ}.EXAMPLE.co/v1/appointments?after=2023-08-14'
```

I suspect this is due to the volume of data being loaded (despite it only being 100 or so rows), but not entirely sure yet.

This script worked just fine a few days ago, I open up the laptop and today it's stuck in this never-ending state of running when hitting the final line of code.
I'll give a snippet of the relevant code below. The final line is where the hang begins and puts the program in a state where it never completes its run.

```
import utils.dbutils as db
import db_config.connection_config as conn
import db_config.credentials as cred
import webbrowser
import utils.apiutils as apu
import api_config.apiconfig as ap
# import pip_package as pp

engine = db.create_sql_server_engine(conn.server, conn.database, cred.username, cred.password, conn.driver)

# pp.install_project_dependencies(requirements_file='dependencies.txt')
authorization_url = apu.authorization_url_fn(ap.authorization_endpoint,
                                             ap.client_id,
                                             ap.redirect_uri,
                                             ap.scope,
                                             ap.response_type)



webbrowser.open(authorization_url)

redirected_url = input("Enter the redirected URL: ")

temp_code = redirected_url.split('?code=')[1]

token_data = {
    'grant_type': ap.grant_type,
    'code': temp_code,
    'redirect_uri': ap.redirect_uri,
    'client_id': ap.client_id,
    'client_secret': ap.client_secret
}

token_generated = apu.token_data(ap.token_endpoint, token_data)

if not token_generated:
    print("Token generation failed.")
    exit()


# Fetch Waiting Lists Data
waiting_lists_data = apu.get_api_paginated(token_generated, ap.waiting_list_endpoint)
waiting_lists_table_name = db.extract_tablename(waiting_lists_data)
waiting_lists_df = db.create_dataframe(waiting_lists_data, waiting_lists_table_name)
waiting_lists_final_df = db.add_timestamp_column(waiting_lists_df)

if not waiting_lists_final_df.empty:
    try:
        db.load_dataframe_to_sql(waiting_lists_final_df, waiting_lists_table_name, engine, 'replace', False)
        print("Waiting Lists Data loaded successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Waiting Lists Data loading failed due to: {e}")
else:
    print("No waiting lists data to load.")



# Fetch accounts data
accounts_data = apu.get_api_paginated(token_generated, ap.accounts_read_endpoint)
accounts_table_name = db.extract_tablename(accounts_data)
accounts_df = db.create_dataframe(accounts_data, accounts_table_name)
accounts_final_df = db.add_timestamp_column(accounts_df)

if not accounts_final_df.empty:
    try:
        db.load_dataframe_to_sql(accounts_final_df, accounts_table_name, engine, 'replace', False)
        print("accounts Data loaded successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"accounts Data loading failed due to: {e}")
else:
    print("No accounts data to load.")


# Fetch acquisition source data
acquisition_source_data = apu.get_api_paginated(token_generated, ap.acquisition_source_read_endpoint)
acquisition_source_table_name = db.extract_tablename(acquisition_source_data)
acquisition_source_df = db.create_dataframe(acquisition_source_data, acquisition_source_table_name)
acquisition_source_final_df = db.add_timestamp_column(acquisition_source_df)

if not acquisition_source_final_df.empty:
    try:
        db.load_dataframe_to_sql(acquisition_source_final_df, acquisition_source_table_name, engine, 'replace', False)
        print("Acquisition Source Data loaded successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Failed to load Acquisition Source Data due to: {e}")
else:
    print("No acquisition source data to load.")
```

Here is the final output code before it hangs:
`Acquisition Source Data loaded successfully` ... then it just stays here forever.

I have tried to run a separate script that loads the data in sections using the same code (as opposed to loading all the tables on one script) and that did seem to work just fine.
But I'd prefer to run just one script that loads all the table of data for me.

I can't find anywhere that addresses this properly so have come here for help.